# Bounded Semivariation and Bounded Variation in locally convex TVS

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Hausdorff locally convex TVS and let $P(X)$ be a family of seminorms on $X$ that generates $\tau$. We consider the following definitions.

**Definition 1.** A function $f:[a,b]\to X$ is of *bounded variation* on $[a,b]$ if for each $p\in P(X)$,
$$TV_{a}^b(f)_p=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n p(f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}))\right\}<\infty$$
where the supremum is taken over all divisions $D=\{[x_{i-1},x_i]\}_{i=1}^n$ of $[a,b].$

**Definition 2.** A function $f:[a,b]\to X$ is of *bounded semi-variation* on $[a,b]$ if for each $p\in P(X)$,
$$STV_{a}^b(f)_p=\sup\left\{p\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i[f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})]\right)\right\}<\infty$$
where the supremum is taken over all divisions $D=\{[x_{i-1},x_i]\}_{i=1}^n$ of $[a,b]$ and $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}, i=1,\cdots,n$ with $|\alpha_i|\le 1.$

I have already checked that **Definition 1 implies Definition 2**. I would like to see an example of a function (if possible) showing that **Definition 2 does not imply Definition 1.**  Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you see the example at the end of [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/442478/85506)?

Comment: Yes, I saw it. There you showed that $g$ is not of bounded variation on $[0,1]$. But then, there are no $\alpha_i's$ in that example. I got a problem of showing that $g$ is of bounded semivariation.

Comment: What's the problem? "summing such differences [multiplied by $\alpha_i$] over any collection of nonoverlapping intervals we get a function of norm $1$".

Comment: Wew, I have to look it again...

Comment: I have already fixed it. Maybe the norm is at most 1.:) Thanks